# Two Constructors in Controller in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

How do I use two constructors in my Controller in my Controller?

I have these two controllers in my `public class OrdersController` and I need them both for CRUD operations both by context and with HttpClientFactory for another API

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;


        // I want to use this constructor as well as 
        [ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]
        public OrdersController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
        {
            this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        }

        private readonly AnimimoMicroservicesNewOrderServiceContext _context;

        // this one
        public OrdersController(AnimimoMicroservicesNewOrderServiceContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Seems like you should have separate controllers

Comment: @DanielA.White Hey, thanks for helping out, I need them both in my controller, is there no way of doing this?

Comment: You can’t construct something twice, so you either need an overload with both arguments, or a property setter or two.

Comment: @HereticMonkey How do I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might you be looking for a constructor that takes two arguments?

```
    public OrdersController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, AnimimoMicroservicesNewOrderServiceContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Robert's solution, or on the other hand you can inject some objects directly into contoller's method using [FromServicesAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromservicesattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) when in necessary.

Example:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

public OrdersController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateOrder([FromServices] AnimimoMicroservicesNewOrderServiceContext context)
{
    var data = context.CallMethod();
    return Ok(data);
}
```